# Can't retrieve data from state using Pinia Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I'm trying to get over the composition API and Pinia with Vue3.

I'm making a call to an external API to fetch some data and store it in the state of the store, my issue here is that when I call this state from my page, it appears to be empty and I can't retrieve the data that I've been calling in the *actions* section of my store. Any ideas where I'm wrong in the process?

*App.vue*

```html
<template>
  <h1>Rick And Morty</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in characters" :key="index">
     {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import { useCharactersStore } from '@/stores/characters'
import { onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
  const useStore = useCharactersStore()
  const characters = useStore.characters
  console.log("Store: " + characters)
  
  onBeforeMount(() => {
    useStore.fetchCharacters()
  })
  
  return { 
    useStore,
    characters
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

*character.js*

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useCharactersStore = defineStore('main', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            characters: [],
            page: 1
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchCharacters() {
            const res = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/')
            const { results } = await res.json()
            this.characters.push(results)
            console.log("Back: " + this.characters)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the entire `results` array is inserted into `characters` as one element:

```js
this.characters.push(results) // ❌
```

To push all `results` into `characters` as individual array elements, use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax) (i.e., `...results`):

```js
this.characters.push(...results) // ✅
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-insert-array-elems-into-array?file=src/stores/characters.js)